# Adb tcpip with ngrok

Tags: android, linux, tcp, adb

im using scrcpy with tcpip for connect my linux to my phone without any cable, its working but im now trying to use an ngrok server to connect to adb over internet, this is my code :

```
ngrok tcp <my-phone-ip>:5555
sudo adb tcpip 5555
sudo adb connect <ngrok_host>
```

But when im typing

```
scrcpy -m 1024 -s <ngrok_host>
```

Im having this output:

```
INFO: scrcpy 1.17 <https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy>
adb: error: failed to get feature set: device '<ngrok_host>' not found
ERROR: "adb push" returned with value 1
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
zsh: abort      scrcpy -m 1024 -s <ngrok_host>
```

Thanks in advance